# LINQ to CSV and object value - TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String

Tags: c#, .net, linq, object, csv

I'm using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library
I have a problem with a field of type object. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
  public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I try read a file, and program throw exception - TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String.

Is it possible to handle a value of type object?

Comment: How would a string translate to an Object? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a csv file is only text, and technically everything in it is a `string`. The linq to csv library can parse simple items like numbers and dates, because it knows how to convert them from a string value. However a type of `object` is too generic. I would recommend retrieving it as a `string` and do any additional parsing after the fact in order to get it into the object type that you need.